# Rental contract concerns?

Tags: netherlands, rental, housing, contracts

I am about to rent house in the Netherlands and I'd like to take your opinions about some rules in the contract or may be you face this in your contract and I should take care of it.

- Maintenance: major on landlord and minor on tenant, I feel like this is very subjective and will lead to a lot of problems but he refused to modify it or write specific things.

> The Tenant  is  obliged  under  the  law (Article 7:217 in  conjunction with 240 of  the  Civil  Code), the present Lease Contract  and  custom  to carry  out  minor  repairs  in, on  or about the Subjects  and  the  Landlord is  obliged  to remedy  other  defects  on  being asked to  do so, unless  this  is  either impossible or would require such an  outlay  of  costs  as  could not reasonably  be  required of  the  Landlord in the  circumstances. The parties  shall  promptly  and  properly, each at  his  own expense, attend  to the improvements, including renewals, required to  do so and which they  are obliged  to attend  to by  law, any  statutory  provision or contractual  obligation.

- The house has a small garden: the maintenance of the garden is on the tenant, not the owner.
- If I said I will leave and decided a check-out date, I should leave on date and be sure the house is clean. For any day I will stay after that, I should pay a fine.

Comment: Minor/major is a standard distinction in many countries. Like everything in contract law there is a degree of interpretation (under the control of the courts) but coming up with another wording would create even more interpretation problems. Basically it means you can't demand your landlord comes to change a lightbulb.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is a common document of terms and conditions which (apply to / are the default template for) all rental contracts and supposedly follow from Dutch law; read its [translation into English](https://www.tijdelijktweewoningen.nl/uploads/files/General%20Terms%20and%20Conditions%20for%20lease%20of%20housing%20accomodation_juli_2003%5B4%5D.pdf).

It looks like at least your maintenance clause is taken directly from there - perhaps the entire thing is the separate document you mentioned.

The wording is definitely vague, but at least you'll know where that wording comes from and why your landlord doesn't want to change it. Maybe s/he's also uncomfortable writing formal documents in English and would rather stick to existing text.

I would say that with regard to your first point, you should try to clarify things without insisting on changing the text (and perhaps suggest an addendum). It's not that there's nothing to worry about, but you don't seem to have leverage to make him/her change his/her mind. Again, try to focus on what kind of maintenance you would want to avoid and see if you can get clarification about that.

As for your second point - it seems reasonable to me that if you rent a house or apartment with a garden, you'd be responsible for the daily maintenance of that garden. It's not as though these things are separate and somebody would just rent the garden.

Finally, about what happens when the contract expires: For the duration of the contract, you pay rent; after the duration of the contract either you pay nothing or you pay something - and that something is a fine. Now, spelling that out in a contract is not the most friendly thing to do, but it's common in many countries (and it's in my contract here). I would say the more interesting things to watch out for are:

- How steep is the fine per day (relative to the monthly rental divided by 30)
- What does the landlord hold against you with which s/he can materialize the fine (e.g. how high is the deposit)

Unfortunately, though, it would be very suspicious if you started arguing about the height of the fine; it gives the impression that you intend to overstay the rent period. The "trick" is to be the person who drafts the contract, which makes the other side need to argue about these unsavory details.

Comment: So, I shouldn't worry about maintenance point ?? as this is the most point I am very worrying about, also I have many friends have bad experience in this point with Dutch landlords !!, I mean if he refuse any add or edit !!

Comment: @AhmedRagheb I'd suggest you ask for examples of what items are considered minor maintenance (such as light bulbs, dripping faucets, running toilets, pest control).

Comment: @Dorothy I asked for that but between me and him property agent, she told me that not possible as "we can't put everything and I need to trust owner more than that" but as I mentioned I have friends have bad experience with Dutch owners before specially with things related to maintenance

Comment: @AhmedRagheb you don't need it in writing, you just need them to explain to you the sorts of things you're responsible for. Telling them that friends have had bad experiences is NOT a good thing. You'd be upset if they told you that they'd had bad experiences with people from your country. You live in a place, expect to take care of everything so that you leave it in the condition it was when you first moved in, or better.

Comment: @AhmedRagheb: I disagree with Dorothy, in the sense that you do need things in writing if you can get them - but if you'll notice my edit, I think that's quite unlikely. You've now added information about there being a middle-man involved, and that rarely helps things. Again, you could try to get the landlord to agree to an addendum - which the realty agency doesn't need to be involved in.

Comment: @Dorothy I won't upset if people of my country were bad example for owners or tenants, I think you misunderstand me when I said "Dutch", I just was telling my case, I live now in Netherlands and I like it very much.

Comment: (-1) Can you stop misleading people about the status of this document? It's simply a template and is only "sort of official" in the sense that it's been published by a trade organisation. It DOES NOT APPLY to all (or, indeed, any) rental contract. What applies is (1) the law (2) the contract you actually signed. Why even bring it up by the way? It does not even add anything to your otherwise fine answer.

Comment: @Gala: With due respect - it is your comment that is misleading. But you're welcome to get in touch with the numerous apartment search websites, realty agencies and so on and convince them to take down that document.

Comment: @einpoklum No need for "With due respect", you're wrong, I showed it to you last time, even the very website you found it makes it very clear. There is nothing to "take down" and I don't need to get in touch with anybody, the confusion is all yours, this document is not what you think it is, **you** made that up.

Comment: But since we apparently to redo this all over again, can you please explain to us how you understand "Model established by the Real Estate Council (ROZ) on 30 July, lodged with the/ Clerk of the Court in The Hague on 31 July 2003 and registered there under num. All liability for detrimental consequences of the use of the model is hereby expressly excluded by the ROZ. ", especially the word "model" and "use of the model"?

Comment: @Gala: First, I toned down the strength of my description since, thinking about it, I can't claim to be an authority on these matters. Still, what you're describing seems to be just a disclaimer - that is, they wrote that based on the law, but if somehow they mis-represented anything they don't take responsibility. It still seems that these conditions (upto wording) are what applies to all contracts.

Comment: @einpoklum I am still in strong disagreement, it can only be one or the other, not both at the same time. If it applies to all contracts, then there is nothing to “misrepresent” and a disclaimer would achieve nothing (the actual wording *is* the rule, there is no standard against which something could be deemed a “mistake”. It's precisely because it's merely a template and does not apply to anything that a disclaimer makes sense.

Comment: Besides “use of the model” is extremely clear, it does not “seem” to apply to all contracts, it's a model you can choose to use… or not. The notion that it would apply to all contracts by default is based on nothing at all (and especially not on the text itself or on the website where you found it).

Comment: @Gala: I'm not going to continue this argument, but you're not more convincing the n'th time you're saying something I've replied to already.

Comment: Look, I get it, comments like these can be quite abrasive and it's unpleasant to have to admit a mistake in this context. But you haven't provided any cogent reply to all the points I have made in the past and my last comment made an entirely new one: How on earth could a document be both be a template and apply to all contracts? Your last edit just made your contention even more absurd. But at this point, I am not so much trying to convince you as explaining the mistake for the benefits of others.

Comment: @Gala: Doubling down, eh? Ok, no problem, let's clarify things again. These terms apply to all contracts because they follow from Dutch law. While it's theoretically possible there's some misrepresented point (which is why a disclaimer is made about using the text of the document), that is not very likely as is evidenced by its widespread use over a prolonged period of time. So, it seems you are the one making mistakes which need to be explained for the benefit of others.

Comment: What mistakes have I made? I just made a very simple point: What applies is the law and the contract you actually signed. I certainly agree that this document probably follows the law, never claimed anything else. But it does not supersede the terms of the contracts or apply by default to anything. Is it so difficult to understand? In fact, I think that now you admitted it's just a template your answer is very close to being correct and reasonable, you're just contorting to avoid walking back your original claim.

Comment: But another clue that might help you understand (and don't pretend to have answered it): If you got to the ROZ website (the original source for all this, *per* the disclaimer I quoted), you will find [a model contract and a manual on how to use it](https://roz.nl/de-roz-modellen/model-woonruimte/). In this contract, you can read “Van deze overeenkomst maken deel uit de 'ALGEMENE BEPALINGEN HUUROVEREENKOMST WOONRUIMTE' […]. Deze algemene bepalingen zijn partijen bekend. Huurder heeft hiervan een exemplaar ontvangen.”

Comment: In clear: Those “Algemene Bepalingen” are just part of the contract **if and only if the contract mentions them** and the tenant has received a copy and agreed to be bound by them (by signing the contract). They do not apply by default nor cover all rental contracts signed in the country.